# Is it possible to mark a parameter as 'sensitive' so that it isn't shown in logs?

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server

Looking at the server logs when a new user signs up via an SDK, one can see the following:

```
verbose: POST /parse/users { 'user-agent': 'node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.8.5 (NodeJS 6.9.1)',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'text/plain',
  host: 'localhost:8888',
  'content-length': '298',
  connection: 'close' } {
    "email": "joe@schmo.com",
    "username": "joe@schmo.com",
    "password": "********"
}
```

In the above, the password has been removed and replaced with *, which is helpful in the case that verbose logging is accidentally turned on in the production environment.

However, if one calls a user defined **Cloud Code** function or uses the REST API, that same information is not hidden.

```
verbose: POST /parse/functions/signUpUser { host: 'localhost:8888',
  'x-parse-client-version': 'i1.13.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  'x-parse-application-id': 'app-id',
  'x-parse-client-key': 'client-key',
  'x-parse-installation-id': 'install-id',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'x-parse-os-version': '10.2 (16D32)',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '76',
  'user-agent': 'App/19 CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/16.4.0',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'x-parse-app-build-version': '19',
  'x-parse-app-display-version': '0.9905' } {
  "username": "joe@schmo.com",
  "password": "password1"
}
```

Is there a way in the headers or similar to indicate that a particular field is sensitive and should not be written to the logs?